# Binding a repeater control from another class

Tags: c#, asp.net, binding, repeater

I am developing an application which uses database query to display data using repeater control.

My repeater control is placed on my page "show.aspx" and I have another class where I have methods for data binding.

So what is the best approach of binding repeater from my data class?

Also, I have made an extension method for repeater, called `BindTable()`;
It is easy for me to bind data by just calling this method in "show.cs" class (I mean on form load). This method takes the sql query as parameter and everything is done in the background by the extension method.

```
rptDisplay.BindTable("select * from table");
```

But I am looking for a better approach. Can't I access my repeater from my data class where all my data binding methods reside?

Comment: What do you mean by "my data class where all my data binding methods reside"? What is the purpose of the "data class", accessing data or doing data binding for controls?

Comment: Let me make it simple! I want to bind datasourse of the repeater from a different class, lets say "abc.cs". Reason for doing this, I want to make code clean. I just want to call a function on form load event and my repeater should dind data. And this function is written in my "abc.cs" class. How this can be achieved?

Comment: Why don't you pass the repeater to the method in your class?

Answer (score 1):

Based upon your comments, your goal is to factor out the code that does the data binding from the form in order to keep your form code clean. This is good as the code for retrieving and binding data can be a big part of your code behind files.
First of all, I think that creating an extension method as you already did is a very good - and elegant - way to approach this. It works well for multiple repeaters on the page and different SQL statements. So how can you further improve this?

Now, you provide the SQL statements to the extension method directly in the code behind. This works, but in order to have a really clean separation of concerns, I'd not suggest to include the statements directly in the UI code as it is a detail of the data access that it uses SQL. If you decide to introduce a service layer at a later point in time that provides the data, you'd have to make lots of changes to your UI code. It is up to you to decide whether this is a realistic scenario in your context that is worth the effort.
The steps are as follows:

1. Create data transfer objects (DTOs) that contain the data that are relevant to your UI.
2. Create data access classes (also known as repository classes) that do not return DataTables/Sets but collections or single DTOs with methods like GetById, GetAll, GetByName that depict the relevant queries to the database. A MicroORM (e.g. Dapper.NET) can support you in the (boring) mapping process from the database objects (DataTables, DataReaders) to the DTOs. Also include methods to update the database.
3. In the form, retrieve the data by a call to the repository and bind the repeater to the collection of DTOs.

After you've introduced these changes, you will notice that it was not the data binding code that made your code behind files grow, but the data access code. Once this code is moved to the repositories, the data binding is just setting the DataSource property and a call to DataBind(). So your extension method will be very small and look similar to this:

```
public static void Bind<T>(this Repeater rpt, IEnumerable<T> data)
{
    rpt.DataSource = data;
    rpt.DataBind();
}
```

This approach requires some effort, but provides a much better separation of concerns as the UI independent data access logic is located in a separate place (maybe you can also share the data access code with other projects for different clients, e.g. WPF or WinForms). Plus, I'm sure that you will be able to identify lots of other spots (besides data binding) where you can also use the repositories instead of accessing the data directly. This will also make your code shorter.

Comment: You got my point exactly. I have used the extension method for binding data for multiple repeaters in my another project. How ever it made my code very less, but I actually didn't like the idea of provinding sql query directly reason was to abstract code.

Comment: I am going to try your method for sure. However my need is very simple. I am just trying to display an article and comments from database. I just want to provide the article id from the querystring and then calling the show method to do everything.

Comment: @askBittu: good to know that I understood your question correctly. You have to judge whether it's too much overhead in the specific situation. On the other hand, a good framework for the MicroORM will do most of the additional work.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a function in the abc class that accepts a repeater as parameter and binds data to it.

**EDIT:** You will probably want to switch datasource for different repeaters. In that case you can add another parameter to `BindTable` method and inside that method check the parameter to switch to proper datasource.

**EDIT 2 :** `BindTable` takes two parameters, `Repeater` and an enum `MyEnum`.

Here's how I would do it. I have a page, **Show.aspx**:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Show.aspx.cs" Inherits="RepeaterTestOne.Show" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Repeater ID="rptDisplay" runat="server">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <table>
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("ID") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </td><td>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <FooterTemplate>
                </table>
            </FooterTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="First One" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="First Four" OnClick="Button2_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="All" OnClick="Button3_Click" />
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In code I am calling BindTable() method of my data class (MyDataClass) and passing the repeater. My **Show.aspx.cs** looks like this:

```
using System;

namespace RepeaterTestOne
{
    public partial class Show : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyDataClass.BindTable(rptDisplay, MyEnum.FirstOne);
        }

        protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyDataClass.BindTable(rptDisplay,MyEnum.FirstFour);
        }

        protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyDataClass.BindTable(rptDisplay, MyEnum.AllItems);
        }
    }
}
```

In my MyDataClass I have code (with dummy code for test) like this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace RepeaterTestOne
{
    public static class MyDataClass
    {
        public static void BindTable(Repeater rpt, MyEnum mySelection = MyEnum.AllItems)
        {

            //Replace this part with custom sql
            List<MyData> lst = new List<MyData>()
            {
                new MyData{ID=1, Name="Item 1"},
                new MyData{ID=2, Name="Item 2"},
                new MyData{ID=3, Name="Item 3"},
                new MyData{ID=4, Name="Item 4"},
                new MyData{ID=5, Name="Item 5"}
            };
            switch (mySelection)
            {
                case MyEnum.FirstOne:
                    lst = new List<MyData>(){new MyData{ID=1, Name="Item 1"}};
                    break;
                case MyEnum.FirstFour:
                    lst = new List<MyData>()
                    {
                        new MyData{ID=1, Name="Item 1"},
                        new MyData{ID=2, Name="Item 2"},
                        new MyData{ID=3, Name="Item 3"},
                        new MyData{ID=4, Name="Item 4"}
                    };
                    break;
                default:
                    lst = new List<MyData>()
                    {
                        new MyData{ID=1, Name="Item 1"},
                        new MyData{ID=2, Name="Item 2"},
                        new MyData{ID=3, Name="Item 3"},
                        new MyData{ID=4, Name="Item 4"},
                        new MyData{ID=5, Name="Item 5"}
                    };
                    break;
            }
            //Replace this part with custom sql

            rpt.DataSource = lst;
            rpt.DataBind();
        }

    }
    public class MyData
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And here's my enum `MyEnum`:

```
namespace RepeaterTestOne
{
    public enum MyEnum
    {
        AllItems = 1,
        FirstOne = 2,
        FirstFour = 3
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok. This seems good while I have just one repeater in my class. But what if I have multiple repeaters in my page? In this way I can't re use the code. I will have to write different functions to bind different repeaters.

Comment: Say you have another repeater with ID="anotherRepeater". You will call it like `MyDataClass.BindTable(anotherRepeater);` . No matter how many repeaters you have, you can call them using this function.

Comment: @askBittu - updated code to show how can you use same function for any numbers of repeater.

Comment: Thankyou so much for explaining it so well. But I think I was not able to explain you properly. By saying multiple repeaters I mean, their different datasources. In your example I will be binding data with the same collection each time.

Comment: I know what you mean... just mentioned that in my edit. I will update my code.

Comment: @askBittu - I have updated the code. In aspx there are three buttons. Each of them will call the function with different parameter and in function we switch to related datasource.

Comment: Well thank you for giving me so much of ideas for implementing this. I will use these concepts for sure.